# Security of storing 3rd party authentication tokens

Tags: architecture

I'm developing a mobile app which uses Facebook authentication tokens to post to Facebook and Instagram pages. The most convenient would be for me store authentication tokens on backend, but I'm afraid if the possibility of someone hacking that database and gaining the access to all the tokens should make me store that data on the frontend instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to access your UI than the backend - Secure your server where yu have DB and then secure your DB with authentication, And last but not least secure the authentication token with further encryption making sure the right people/user can decrypt it.

UI has so many reasons not to use it for storage for such secure data.